# SQL, Sum between dates X and X based on a variable

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I am struggling a bit with this problem, I do entry level work at a school that is based on hours.

I need to find all students who have passed their registration end date and get a sum of these students hours from their 1st attendance date to the registration end date. This is the start of the code I have written but I know my Case is wrong.

An example Student A has a Attendance date greater then his Contract end date.

At Contract end date his total hours = 560

The minimum to complete this program is 600 hours

We then add a surcharge to those 40 hours that he has not completed by end date.

I can do the math, I just need to get it where I can physically get the students. If I add anything such as Where ATD.Attendancedate >= Reg.enddate it of course will only pull hours past the End date.

```
  SELECT CONCAT('<a href="admin_view_student.jsp?studentid=', 
     CAST(SDT.studentId AS CHAR), '">', CAST(SDT.firstName AS bCHAR), ' ', 
    CAST(SDT.lastName AS CHAR), '</a>') AS Name,
    PGM.programmeName AS 'Program',
     FORMAT(SUM(ATD.duration),2) AS 'Total Hours',
    PGM.MinClockHours AS 'Program Total',
     ATD.attendancedate AS 'ATTDATE',
REG.Enddate AS 'EndDate',
Case WHEN MAX(ATD.attendancedate) >= REG.Enddate Then  Sum(ATD.duration) Between MIN(ATD.attendancedate) AND REG.enddate
ELSE NULL END AS 'Whatever' 
FROM Attendance ATD
INNER JOIN Registrations    REG ON ATD.studentId = 
      REG.studentId AND  REG.isActive = 1
INNER JOIN Programmes       PGM ON REG.programmeId 
    = PGM.programmeId AND  PGM.isActive = 1
INNER JOIN Students         SDT ON REG.studentId = 
     SDT.studentId AND SDT.isactive = 1
  WHERE
    REG.ADMINID                         AND
    REG.enrollmentSemesterId = 4000441  AND
     PGM.programmename Not like ('Careers Pathway') AND PGM.programmename Not like ('Instructor Training') AND
    ATD.subjectId IN (SELECT GSR.subjectId
            FROM CourseGroups CGP
            INNER JOIN GroupSubjectReltn GSR ON CGP.courseGroupId=GSR.courseGroupId AND GSR.isActive=1
            WHERE REG.programmeId = CGP.programmeId and CGP.isActive=1)
                                        AND
    ATD.classId IN (SELECT DISTINCT CRS.classId
            From ClassStudentReltn CRS
            Where CRS.studentId = ATD.studentId AND CRS.isActive=1)
GROUP BY SDT.lastname
ORDER BY SDT.firstName
```

Comment: *not sure about the case expression containing SUM() normally it works the other way around. e.g.* SUM(Case WHEN MAX(ATD.attendancedate) >= REG.Enddate and ATD.attendancedate Between MIN(ATD.attendancedate) AND REG.enddate then ATD.duration end)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this pretty straightforwardly with a self-join.  You need to select the students in question based on `Where ATD.Attendancedate >= Reg.enddate` and then do your calculations on just the students that meet that condition.  So:

```
[your query]
inner join 
    (SELECT studentId
    FROM Attendance ATD
    inner join Registrations REG
    ON ATD.studentId = REG.studentId 
        AND  REG.isActive = 1
    WHERE ATD.Attendancedate >= Reg.enddate) as late
on [your query].studentId = late.studentId
```